# Why does this anonymous function return undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to create a `forEach()` function that takes an array and a function, then performs the function action on each element of the array. However, when trying to pass the below anonymous function, I get `undefined`. I tried adding a `return` to the `forEach()` function after reading some other posts but then the function doesn't run at all and just returns the first `array[i]` it receives without modifying it.

```
function forEach(array, action){
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   action(array[i]);
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var something = forEach(myArray, function(element){return element++;});
console.log(something)
//undefined
```

That returns `undefined`.

```
function forEach(array, action){
 for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
   return action(array[i]);
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var something = forEach(myArray, function(element){return element++;});
console.log(something)
//undefined
```

That returns `1`.

What am I missing?

(I am aware a .forEach() function exists, I am trying this as a learning exercise)

Comment: First function doesn't have a `return` statement. Second one has a loop that exits on first iteration. It's a strange learning exercise anyway.

Comment: what are you expecting forEach to return ?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález he is trying to implement forEach him self. It's a perfectly valid learning exercise I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach` implementation is correct - it shouldn't return anything. If you want `map` (i.e. transform an argument into a new array), you can implement `reduce` first:

```
function reduce(array, action, result) {
    forEach(array, function (elem) {
        result = action(result, elem);
    });
    return result;
}
```

and then, define `map` via `reduce`:

```
function map(array, action) {
    return reduce(array, function (result, elem) {
        return result.concat(action(elem));
    }, []);
}
```

Putting it all together:

```js
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        action(array[i]);
}

function reduce(array, action, result) {
    forEach(array, function (elem) {
        result = action(result, elem);
    });
    return result;
}

function map(array, action) {
    return reduce(array, function (result, elem) {
        return result.concat(action(elem));
    }, []);
}

a = map([1, 2, 3, 4], function (x) {
    return ++x
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 3));
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `forEach` function doesn't return anything. It looks like you're trying your hand at a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) implementation. If so, you need to add your results to a new array and return that array.

```
function map(array, action) { // Renamed forEach to a more suitable name
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    results.push(action(array[i]));
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: don't name a returning function "forEach", name it "map" to avoid confusion